# Accessing socket controller from model in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, socket.io

So I'm working on a school project and we've got a code template.
I have a mysql database running, and whenever a certain table gets an insert, I want anyone viewing the table on the website to have it updated using socket.io.
But I cannot access the socketcontroller from the model, nor from the routecontroller(where I call the model). I understand that it's probably best practice to return the inserted data back to the controller(via callback) and then in the controller emit the message using io.

in index.js

```
var httpServer = http.Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(httpServer);
io.use(sharedsession(session));

var router = require('./controller.js');
app.use('/API', router);

var socketController = require('./socketController.js');
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socketController(socket, io);
});
var model = require('./model.js');
```

in socketController.js

```
module.exports = function (socket, io) {
    socket.on('join', function (req) {
        console.log(req);
        var security = req.security;
        socket.join(security);
    });

    socket.on('update', function (req) {
        //this is the function i want to "call" from the model/routecontroller
    });
}
```

in controller.js

```
router.post('/orders', function(req, res) {
    //var socket = io(); <--- not defined
    model.matchOrder(req.body, function(result) {
        res.json({order: req.body});
    })
});
```

in model.js

```
function createTrade(security, price, amount, buyer, seller) {
    console.log("Trade created");
    //var socket = io()    <-- not defined 
    Trades.create({
      security: security,
      price: price,
      amount: amount,
      buyer: buyer,
      seller: seller
    });
```

}

So 1. Where should i try to access the socket, in controller.js or model.js?
and 2. How do i get access to io() from controller.js/model.js?